# Synthax related, using a interpolation inside an angular2 method call

Tags: angular

```
    <div *ngFor="let track of album.tracks.items">
    <div class="well">
        <h5>{{track.track_number}} - {{track.name}}</h5>
        <span (click)="addToPlaylist(track.uri)" >{{track.uri}}</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Whenever I click that span it sends it to the service as "undefined"

```
addToPlaylist(track:string){
    let user = 'user id here';
    let playlistId = 'playlist id here'
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer --auth token here--`);

    this.addTrackUrl= 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/'+user+'/playlists/'+playlistId+'/tracks?uris='+track;

    return this._http
    .post(this.addTrackUrl, {}, { headers })
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

That's what the method looks like in case you need it. I've tried using curly braces inside the parenteses, all I tried just gave me an error or undefined

[image: undefined uri]

Comment: which is undefined? error logged in console.

Comment: show us your function in your component to call the function in your service :)

Comment: @AJT_82 your comment helped me find the problem, my function in the component looked like this had no parameters in it, silly me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass uri like this way.

```
addToPlaylist(track:string){
        let user = 'user id here';
        let playlistId = 'playlist id here'
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer --auth token here--`);

        let data = new Object();
        data.uris = track;

        this.addTrackUrl= 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/'+user+'/playlists/'+playlistId+'/tracks';

        return this._http
        .post(this.addTrackUrl, data, { headers })
        .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong either with my POST body being empty or with the function call, the problem was in my component which I did not include in the question;

This was the function in my component

```
addToPlaylist() {
    this._spotifyServer.addToPlaylist().subscribe(res => {
        this.added = res;
    });
}
```

And this is how it looks now, working fine

```
addToPlaylist(track) {
    this._spotifyServer.addToPlaylist(track).subscribe(res => {
        this.added = res;
    });
}
```

It wasn't synthax related, if someone is facing the same problem, don't forget to check the template, the component and the service!

Thanks @AJT_82 for suggesting to check my component!